# Add subclass to super class' list when subclass is created in Python?

Tags: python, class, subclass, superclass

Suppose I have a base class as following:

```
class User:
    user_types = []
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

And then I want to create a subclass, which will then be added to user_types

```
class Farmer(User):
    def harvest(self):
        print("%s just harvested his plantation!" %self.name)
```

Now I can achieve what I'm trying to do, by simply saying

```
User.user_types.append(Farmer)
```

But how could I achieve this if I wanted it to be automatic, and to be done for every subclass? Let's say there will be 400 subclasses, it would be a pain in the ass to manually do that for all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

New style classes have this functionality:

```
>>> User.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.Farmer'>]
```

Just need to make `User` inherit from `object` in case you're using Python 2.x.

If you need all the subclasses of each subclass, you can still avoid metaclasses with this:

```
def get_subclasses(c):
    subs = set(c.__subclasses__())
    return subs.union(*(get_subclasses(i) for i in subs))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a metaclass do solve your problem:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(meta, classname, bases, classDict):
        new_class = type.__new__(meta,classname,bases,classDict)
        for base in bases:
            if hasattr(base,'register'):
                base.register(new_class)
        return new_class

class Base(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    subclasses = []

    @classmethod
    def register(cls,derived):
        cls.subclasses.append(derived)


class A(Base):
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C(Base):
    pass

print Base.subclasses
```

The output is:

```
[<class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>]
```